# Laravel + vue pusher система диалогов

Tags: laravel, vue.js, push-уведомления, realtime, broadcasting

Как решить проблемы:

1. Когда выбрал диалог - подключился к каналу для обмена сообщениями, все работает, но когда я нажимаю например на Избранные, то загружаются избранные диалоги, но если пользователь мне еще пишет, с которым я переписывался, то на вкладке избранные от него идут сообщения, получается что я не отписался от канала? как это сделать?
2. Когда я выбрал диалог и переписываюсь с пользователем, то почему-то не срабатывает метод `isTyping`

событие DialogMessage

```
public $data;
public $chat_id;
public function __construct($data,$chat_id)
{
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->chat_id = $chat_id;
}
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('chat.' . $this->chat_id);
}
```

есть меню, для ввода сообщение

```
<button type="button" @click.prevent="Dialogs()"> Все сообщения</button>
<button type="button" @click.prevent="dialogFavorites()"> Избранное</button>
```

вывод списка диалогов

```
<div class="contact-list__items" v-for="(dialog, index) in dialogs" @click.prevent="selectUser(dialog.id,dialog.user,index,dialog.avatar,dialog.fullname)">
        <p class="username">{{dialog.fullname}}</p>
</div>
```

вывод сообщений

```
<ul class="chat--messages__wrapper">
  <li class="chat--messages__item" v-for="(message,index) in messages">
    <div class="chat--user__data">
      <p class="last--massage" v-html="message.replay"></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

поле для ввода текста

```
<p v-if="isTyping">{{ isTyping.name}} набирает сообщение</p>
<textarea v-model="message" @keydown="actionUser"></textarea>
```

код Vue

```
export default {
        name: "Dialogs",
        data: function () {
            return {
                userAuth: {
                    id: 0,
                    avatar: '',
                    fullname: ''
                },
                isTyping: false, //Пользователь набирает сообщение
                typingTimer: false,
                dialogs: [],
                messages: [],
                message: "",
                dialogSelect: 0,
                userSelect: {
                    id: 0,
                    avatar: '',
                    fullname: ''
                },
                dialogIndex: 0,
                messageDate: '',
                offset: 0,
                limit: 40,
                activeFilter : 'all',
                dialog: { //Для выпадающего меню, с дествиями над диалогом
                    like : 0,
                    favorite: 0,
                    ignore: 0
                }
            }
        },
        created(){

        },
        watch: {
        },
        computed: {
            channel(){
                return  window.Echo.private('chat.' + this.dialogSelect);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.User();
            this.Dialogs();
        },
        methods: {
            pushMessage(){
                if (this.dialogSelect > 0){
                    this.channel
                        .listen('DialogMessage',({data}) => {
                            this.messages.push(data);
                            this.isTyping = false;
                        })
                        .listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
                            console.log(e);
                            this.isTyping = e;

                            if (this.typingTimer) clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);

                            this.typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                                this.isTyping = false;
                            }, 2000);
                        });
                }

            },
            sendMessage(){
                axios.post('/profile/dialogs/send',{
                    message:this.message,
                    chat_id: this.dialogSelect,
                    user_id: this.userSelect.id,
                    type: 1
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.message = '';
                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            },
            actionUser(){
                console.log(this.userAuth.fullname);
                this.channel
                    .whisper('typing', {
                        name: this.userAuth.fullname
                    });
            },
            selectUser(id,user,x,avatar, fullname){
              this.dialogSelect  = id;
              this.userSelect.id  = user;
              this.userSelect.avatar  = avatar;
              this.userSelect.fullname  = fullname;
              this.dialogIndex  = x;
                axios.post('/profile/dialogs/messages',{
                    dialog_id: id,
                    offset: this.offset,
                    limit: this.limit
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.messages = response.data.messages;
                        this.dialog.like = response.data.like;
                        this.dialog.favorite = response.data.favorite;
                        this.dialog.ignore = response.data.ignore;
                        this.pushMessage();
                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            },
            dialogFavorites(){
                this.dialogNone();
                axios.get('/profile/dialogs/favorites')
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.dialogs = response.data;
                        this.activeFilter = 'f';
                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            },
            Dialogs(){
                this.dialogNone();
                axios.get('/profile/dialogs')
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.dialogs = response.data;
                        this.activeFilter = 'all';

                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            },
            User(){
                axios.get('/profile/me/auth')
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.userAuth.id = response.data.id;
                        this.userAuth.avatar = response.data.avatar;
                        this.userAuth.fullname = response.data.fullname;

                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            },
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

сделал выход из канала

```
destroyChannel(){
  window.Echo.leave('chat.' + this.dialogSelect);
},
```